# Clam av automation issues (not performing auto scan ) in bash script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, anti-virus, bash-scripting, clamav

To automate ClamAV and monitor a specific directory for new file uploads, including all files and folders, excluding encrypted zip archives from scanning, I attempted to implement inotifywait with the recursive option and clams can --remove --recursive to initiate scans on new file uploads. However, the script did not perform auto scans, even after testing with sudo privileges and confirming that ClamAV and its services were running properly. Additionally, the output from inotifywait indicated that it was detecting changes in the directory. I even tested the script using the EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE, but it still did not initiate auto-scans for newly created files. Manual scans worked as expected."

What is the issue here, any help would be apricated.

```
# Other parts of the code ...

# Specify the folder to monitor
folder_to_monitor=/customers/incoming/

# Specify the folder for logs
log_folder=/var/log/clamav

# Specify the folder for Excel reports
report_folder="/var/reports/clamav"


# Start monitoring the folder
sudo inotifywait -m $folder_to_monitor -e create -e moved_to |
while read path action file; do
    if [[ "$file" =~ .*\.zip$ ]]; then
        # If a ZIP file is detected, check if it is encrypted
        if unzip -tq "$path$file" >/dev/null; then
            # If the ZIP file is not encrypted, perform the scan on the extracted files
            unzip -q -o -d "$folder_to_monitor" "$path$file"
            log_file=$log_folder/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)_clamscan.log
            sudo clamscan --remove --recursive --allmatch --infected --exclude=$folder_to_monitor/*.zip --exclude=$folder_to_monitor/*.enc "$folder_to_monitor"
            clamscan_exit_code=$?
        else
            # If the ZIP file is encrypted, skip the scan
            continue
        fi
    elif [[ "$file" =~ .*\.enc$ ]]; then
        # If an encrypted file is detected, skip the scan
        continue
    else
        # If a new file of any type is detected, run ClamAV scan on the file
        log_file=$log_folder/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)_clamscan.log
        sudo clamscan --remove --recursive --allmatch --infected "$path$file"
        clamscan_exit_code=$?
   fi

    # If a virus is detected, create an Excel report and send it to Sentry
    if [ $clamscan_exit_code -eq 1 ]; then
        create_excel_report
        # Append the output of the ClamAV scan to the log file
        clamscan --remove --recursive --allmatch --infected --exclude=$folder_to_monitor/*.zip --exclude=$folder_to_monitor/*.enc "$folder_to_monitor" >> $log_file
        sentry-cli send-event -m "Virus detected in file: $path$file" --log-file $log_file --attach-file $report_file --dsn $sentry_dsn
    fi
done

# Function to run the scan and delete infected files without quarantine
run_scan() {
    # Scan the folder and delete infected files without quarantine
    clamscan --remove --recursive --allmatch --infected --exclude=$folder_to_monitor/*.zip --exclude=$folder_to_monitor/*.enc --exclude=$folder_to_monitor/*.rar --exclude=$folder_to_monitor/*.tar --exclude=$folder_to_monitor/*.gz --exclude=$folder_to_monitor/*.bz2 --exclude=$folder_to_monitor/*.7z --exclude=$folder_to_monitor/*.iso $folder_to_monitor > $log_file

    # Create the Excel report
    create_excel_report
}

# Run the initial scan
log_file=$log_folder/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)_clamav_scan.log
run_scan

# Watch for changes in the folder and run the scan again if necessary
while inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete,move $folder_to_monitor; do
    # Run the scan again
    log_file=$log_folder/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)_clamav_scan.log
    run_scan
done

# Add the cron job to run the scan every minute
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "*/1 * * * * $USER $HOME/clamav_scan.sh cron") | crontab -

# Check if the script was called with the "cron" argument and run the scan from the system cron job
if [[ $# -eq 1 && $1 == "cron" ]]; then
    log_file=$log_folder/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)_clamav_cron_scan.log
    cron_scan
fi

# Run the initial scan and generate a report
generate_report

# Set up a cron job to generate reports every hour
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "0 * * * * $(which bash) -c 'cd $(pwd) && ./clamav_scan.sh --generate-report'") | crontab -
```

Comment: Have you see Fitzcarraldo's implementation of a scan based on new file arriving, https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/20/automatically-detecting-files-placed-in-my-downloads-directory-in-gentoo-linux-and-scanning-them-for-viruses/ ?